# Data search in sql, on teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need found in table information about close the deal, i have start data and day's when spent on deal.
I'm trying to sum up the start date and the number of days. it doesn't work out in any way.
Like integer + date, but this don't working.
Interval don't working because need check 2k+ rows.
Someone can help?

```
start_data           do_days 
10.11.2020           40
```

I need to start data add days of deal. And get the date, in this sample 20.12.2020

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Post some sample data and desired results, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana
Sample of data
`start_data           do_days
10.11.2020           40`

I need to start data add days of deal. And get the date, in this sample 20.12.2020

Comment: @donnishe add it to your question , as well as your desired output

Comment: If something "isn't working" then show what you tried and the resulting error or unexpected output.

Answer (score 0):

you can add that as interval o your date:

```
select start_data + do_days 
from table
```

Comment: this select failed with error "interval filed overflow", that strange first seeing that error

Comment: INTERVAL types in Teradata are in general limited to 4-digit precision, e.g. 9999 days. But if you simply add an integer to a date, Teradata treats the integer as a number of days, without imposing the INTERVAL precision limit.

Comment: Holy cow, all these years, I never knew could add days without the interval syntax

Comment: @Fred
Can u do example for select? don't understand u

Comment: @eshirvana how u do this. i try this 4 times, but i haved error, but now that working. Thank you

Comment: @donnishe great, please accept/ upvote if this helped

Answer (score 0):

Can you try  select TO_CHAR( start_date + do_days) from table.